# Interpreting out of bag error estimate for RandomForestRegressor

Tags: regression, random-forest

I am using RandomForest regressor on my data and I could see that the oob score was obtained to be 0.83. I am not sure how it came out to be like this. I mean my targets are high values in the range of 10^7. So if it's MSE then it should have been much higher. I don't understand what 0.83 signify here.

I am using python's RandomForestRegressor of the sklearn toolkit.

I do

model = RandomForestRegressor(max_depth=7, n_estimators=100, oob_score=True, n_jobs=-1)
model.fit(trainX, trainY )

Then I see model.oob_score_ and I get values like 0.83809026152005295

Comment: @Momo. I am using python's sklearn.ensemble's RandomForestRegressor. I just use the model like

Answer (score 7):

In order to compare the ground truth (i.e. correct/actual) target values with estimated (i.e. predicted) target values by the random forest , scikit-learn doesn't use the MSE but $R^2$ (unlike e.g. [MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/regressionbaggedensemble.oobloss.html) or ([Breiman 1996b](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~breiman/OOBestimation.pdf))), as you can see in the code of [forest.py](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/ensemble/forest.py):

```
self.oob_score_ = 0.0
for k in xrange(self.n_outputs_):
    self.oob_score_ += r2_score(y[:, k], predictions[:, k])
self.oob_score_ /= self.n_outputs_
```

[`r2_score()`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/metrics/metrics.py) computes the [coefficient of determination aka. R2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination), whose best possible score is 1.0, and lower values are worse.

FYI:

- [What is the out of bag error in Random Forests?](https://www.quora.com/Machine-Learning/What-is-the-out-of-bag-error-in-Random-Forests)
- [What is the difference between “coefficient of determination” and “mean squared error”?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/32596/12359)
- Breiman, Leo. [Out-of-bag estimation](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~breiman/OOBestimation.pdf). Technical report, Statistics Department, University of California Berkeley, Berkeley CA 94708, 1996b. 33, 34, 1996.