# R-squared vs MSE, why the discrepancy?

Tags: model-selection, missing-data, r-squared, model-evaluation, mse

I am carrying out a project where I am imputing missing data.  I am trying to compare an imputed dataset with a baseline dataset by measuring MSE and R-squared.  These metrics are measured by performing linear regression and carrying out 10-fold cross validation.

The problem is that for the baseline dataset I get MSE = 85.0 and R-squared = 45.5;  and for the imputed dataset I get MSE = 97.6 and R-squared = 47.2.

So we see that the MSE is lower (better) for the baseline but the R-squared is higher (better) for the imputed dataset.

I am trying to see if the imputed dataset is a better choice than the baseline, but I am now confused as to which metric to choose.

Both datasets have the same features (16) and target feature.  The features include both categorical and continuous features.  The target is a continuous feature.  The baseline has 814 observations;  the imputed set has 879.  They have not been scaled or normalized.

Please could you advise on why there is no clear "winner"?  Which metric should I choose?  Etc.

Thank you very much.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/100281/selecting-the-best-model-using-cross-validation-on-coefficient-of-determination?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting the best model using cross-validation on coefficient of determination and/or mean squared error](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/100281/selecting-the-best-model-using-cross-validation-on-coefficient-of-determination)

Comment: It's **not** a duplicate: the issue here is models fitted before vs after imputation.

Comment: How does your software calculate $MSE$ and $R^2?$