# How to choose a linear regression model when feature selection is used?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, feature-selection

What is best way to choose a criterion for linear regression model performance? Should the best model refer to RMSE, adjusted R-squared or AIC values?

What about when variable selection methods such as stepwise, backward or forward elimination are applied?

Answer (score 1):

RMSE and R-squared are both measures of [goodness of fit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodness_of_fit), used to assess the quality of a model, and are [directly related](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32596/what-is-the-difference-between-coefficient-of-determination-and-mean-squared).

On the other hand, AIC is an information criterion used to compare a group of models (i.e., unless you can compare the AIC value of a model with others, it has not much use). According to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion):

> Given a collection of models for the data, AIC estimates the quality
>   of each model, relative to each of the other models

The guidelines above do not change if you use a feature-selection procedure or not. Nonetheless, adjusted R-squared is usually used to compare models on feature selecion, check [this link](https://www.ritchieng.com/machine-learning-evaluate-linear-regression-model/#14.-Feature-Selection) for a brief intro on this.

In general, using adjusted R-squared will lead you to models with better predictive power, while AIC will allow you to select the simplest, yet efficient model. Again, from wiki:

> AIC deals with the trade-off between the goodness of fit of the model
>   and the simplicity of the model. In other words, AIC deals with both
>   the risk of overfitting and the risk of underfitting.